# Error running app with Firestore in release mode

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I have incorporated `Firestore` into my app for basic reads and writes to some tables. The app works fine in debug mode but when I generate the release build, the following error occurs:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Internal error in Firestore (0.6.6-dev).
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.g.zza.a(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.0.5:14)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.g.zzd.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6649)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:826)
     Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "com.google.protobuf.Internal$ProtobufList com.google.protobuf.Internal$ProtobufList.b(int)"
        at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite.a(GeneratedMessageLite.java:36)
        at com.google.b.a.zzan.a(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.0.5:91)
        at com.google.b.a.zzan$zza.a(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.0.5:2)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.f.zzn.b(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.0.5:28)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.c.zzh.a(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.0.5:59)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.c.zzav.b(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.0.5:8)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.c.zzi.a(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.0.5:52)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.c.zzp.run(Unknown Source:6)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.c.zzat.a(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.0.5:15)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.c.zzi.a(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.0.5:43)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.b.zzac.a(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.0.5:5)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.b.zzd.a(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.0.5:9)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.b.zzg.c(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.0.5:1)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.b.zzo.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:458)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.g.zza$zza.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.0.5:3)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

There doesn't seem to be any configuration issue. How can this be remedied?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51299905/java-lang-runtimeexception-internal-error-in-firestore-0-6-6-dev-after-updati/51327511) out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying out a few things; the scenario that worked was using the following combination of lib versions:

- `com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.0`
- `com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0`
- `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0`

I was using `gradle version 3.3.0-alpha11` and `google services v4.0.1` which are incompatible hence the crashes.

Answer (score 0):

**Clear the data in the application manager on the device.**

Then run the app again.

Ref:[Internal error in Firestore (0.6.6-dev) when trying to update document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46676480/internal-error-in-firestore-0-6-6-dev-when-trying-to-update-document)

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. However, it still wouldn't be a viable option in a production scenario with existing users.

Comment: You tried it on your debugging phone or a completely new phone?

Comment: I've tried it on both my debugging phone and a new one as well.

Answer (score 0):

I´ve also got an error with Firebase Firestore JUST in production mode. I tried the previous answer but it didnt worked for me so I tried different combinations and the following one worked perfectly for me:

```
dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
            classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        }
```