# Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Internal error in Firestore (0.6.6-dev), can't connect between my app and firestore project

Tags: android, xamarin, google-cloud-firestore

I am making a project for school and I am trying to connect my app with a cloud firestore project I made.
while running my app on debugging I found out it crushes only after it runs through my code.
Here's my code:

I am getting the instance of my database throgh this line:

```
database = Singleton.getInstance(this).DataBase;
```

this is the Singlton class:

```
public class Singleton
{
    private static Singleton instance = null;

    private FirebaseFirestore database;

    private Singleton(Context context)
    {

        var options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .SetProjectId("invitedatabase-c75c9")
            .SetApplicationId("invitedatabase-c75c9")
            .SetApiKey("AIzaSyAXLdrHg7GP2p7LKT1WSTIhdkG-41lWCoA")
            .SetDatabaseUrl("https://invitedatabase-c75c9.firebaseio.com")
            .SetStorageBucket("invitedatabase-c75c9.appspot.com")
            .Build();

        FirebaseApp myApp = FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(context, options, "connection");
        database = FirebaseFirestore.GetInstance(myApp);

    }

    public FirebaseFirestore DataBase { get => database; set => database = value; }

    public static Singleton getInstance(Context context)
    {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new Singleton(context);

        return instance;
    }
}
```

then i have a button that's supposed to make the action of transferring data into my database, but even though the debugger shows no exception while it's click function runs:

```
 {
    HashMap map = new HashMap();
    map.Put("full name", et1.Text);
    DocumentReference docref = database.Collection("Users").Document();
    docref.Set(map);
 }
```

after the click function for this button finishes, My app goes into ***break mode*** and throws the exception in the title :

> Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Internal error in Firestore (0.6.6-dev)

Please help me figure this out, I have no idea what this exception means and I'd appreciate any help fixing it and explanation for the problem, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems - as per this other question on the Community solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46684745/12767257) - that this is related to the data on the application manager of your device. I would recommend you give it a try.

After that, as per these other two questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51299905/java-lang-runtimeexception-internal-error-in-firestore-0-6-6-dev-after-updati/51327511) and  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50739346/java-lang-runtimeexception-internal-error-in-firestore-0-6-6-dev/50739467), there are some options that might help you prevent to face this error again, that I would recommend you to take a look for future reference. :)

Please, let me know if the information helped you!